# JQuery: How to Use IF statement correctly?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have confuse how to use IF statement correctly for this case.
I have some command like:

```
if($('#use').val() == "choose") {
        //dialog show
        }
```

i want if `$('#use')` value like "boom","choose","foo","bar" can open the dialog.
How to write the correct command for this case?

---

its mean (by logical thinking):

```
if(#use) value "choose" or "boom" or "foo" or "bar" then dialog show
```

Comment: you want only for some specific value...or  #use can have any value?

Comment: @vivek:#use can have any value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have an extra parenthesis. `"choose")) {` should be `"choose") {`.

```
if ($('#use').val() == "choose") {
    //dialog show
}
```

Or splitting it into multiple lines might make the intention clearer.

```
var canOpenDialog = $('#use').val() == "choose";
if (canOpenDialog) {
    //dialog show
}
```

---

**UPDATE** for your edit. You can use `$.inArray` to check for multiple values.

```
var options = ["boom","choose","foo","bar"];

var canOpenDialog = $.inArray(($('#use').val()),options) != -1;
if (canOpenDialog) {
    //dialog show
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var useValue = $('#use').val();
if (useValue == "choose" || useValue == "boom" || useValue == "foo" || useValue == "bar") {
  //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Figure if you want to add one more later, or just change one. Also there is unnecessary repetition. We have arrays, so why not use them?

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`$.inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/).

It will return the index of the searched string in the chosen `Array`, else return `-1`

```
var values = ["boom","choose","foo","bar"];

if ($.inArray($('#use').val(),values) != -1) {
    // do stuff if "boom" is in the array
} else {
    // do stuff if it is not.
}
```

Comment: This must be call value one by one,isn't it?

Comment: Yes indeed. You want to check all the possible values in a single if-statement ?

Comment: Then you just have to check if `$('#use').val()` is in the Array.

Comment: +1 inArray seems to be the cleanest way. You can easily manipulate the values to check against by changing the array. If you use several conditions connected by `||` in an `IF` it is not easily maintainable and not clean.

Answer (score 0):

better option is to use $.inArray()

```
var required= ["boom","choose","foo","bar"];
if ($.inArray(($('#use').val()),required) != -1) {
    // do Whatever you want
}
```